# AllowDrop does not appear in intellisense menu

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Why does the AllowDrop property in VB.net not appear in the intellisense menu of a control?

Also why is it not in the propeties window of the designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at

[picturebox allowdrop property missing?](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=356884)

> There might be something stated about
>   this on MSDN perhaps? the picturebox
>   class seems to override that property
>   and hide it from the user. See for
>   yourself in Reflector if you want it
>   sets browsable to false, and
>   editbrowsabel to never

And [Drag and Drop Text](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0803041&page=2)

> For most controls, you can set the
>   AllowDrop property in the Properties
>   window during design time. However,
>   some controls (such as the PictureBox
>   control) do not expose this property
>   in the Properties window. As such, you
>   need to dynamically set them in code
>   (note that IntelliSense will not show
>   the AllowDrop property).

Comment: Thanks for the info, it still doesn't really explain why though. Well at least it works... for now.